# Fancybox with URLs

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I want to get URL in address bar when i open fancybox jQuery. link is below:

http://luutaa.co.in/viewfoo/

To open fancybox just click on first image.

Comment: Do you want to know "How to open FancyBox" or what? Please be specific.

Comment: i just want to show url or ID in address bar when fancybox open.

Comment: @GurminderSingh: He wants his question closed asap. He's doing it good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering after viewing the page source of link that you have provided in the question. You should place an *anchor* tag with *href* pointing towards your url, for e.g. :

```
<a id="pop1" href="http://luutaa.co.in/viewfoo/view-template"><img src="http://luutaa.co.in/viewfoo/images/statue-liberty.jpg"></a>
```

And in the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#pop1").fancybox();
});
```

I hope this is worth a try!

Comment: See http://www.pinterest.com and click any image and see in address bar..